# How to merge two rows in one if there is one same value in a column and change columns name

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this query

```
SELECT
    pm.post_id,
    pm.meta_key,
    pm.meta_value
FROM 
   birr_postmeta as pm,
   birr_posts as p
WHERE pm.meta_key IN ('ratings_average', 'ratings_users')
    AND pm.meta_value <> 0
    AND pm.post_id = p.ID
ORDER BY pm.post_id ASC
```

that return me this:

[image]

What I want to obtain, from these table, is something like this

```
+--------+---------------+--------------+
|post_id |  rating_users |rating_average|
+--------+---------------+--------------+
|    7   |       1       |      5       |
|   35   |       3       |      4       |
|   101  |       2       |     4.5      |
|   127  |       2       |      4       |
|   225  |       1       |      4       |
+--------+---------------+------------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT pm.post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'ratings_average' THEN pm.meta_value END) as ratings_average,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'ratings_users' THEN pm.meta_value END) as ratings_users
FROM  birr_postmeta pm 
WHERE pm.meta_key IN ('ratings_average', 'ratings_users')
      pm.meta_value <> 0
GROUP BY pm.post_id ASC;
```

Note that no `JOIN` is necessary.  But if you were to use one, you should use proper `JOIN` syntax.